# How do I create multiple markers for google maps in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I'm unable to find an answer as to how I place several markers on a google map in an iOS app. I know it can be done but I don't know how to do it. This is using some google documentation but my app will display NYC locations.
Here's my very-wrong code:
In GoogleMapsViewController.m I have the following code:

```
//  GoogleMapsViewController.m
//  GoogleMaps1
//
//  Created by Meghan on 2/1/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Meghan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GoogleMapsViewController.h"
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>

@interface GoogleMapsViewController ()

@end

@implementation GoogleMapsViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    {
        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                                longitude:151.20
                                                                     zoom:6];
        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        self.view = mapView_;

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map (center for Sydney).

        NSMutableArray *markersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
            id sydney = [markersArray objectAtIndex:0];
            GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
            marker.title = @"Sydney";
            marker.snippet = @"Australia";
            marker.map = mapView_;

            id newcastle = [markersArray objectAtIndex:1];
            GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-32.92, 151.78);
            marker1.title = @"Newcastle";
            marker1.snippet = @"Australia";
            marker1.map = mapView_;
        }
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Please clearly explain your issue. Are you unable to even add a marker or issue is for adding multiple markers only?

Comment: I had wanted to add multiple markers and I found a way to make it work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to make it work. I simply added the location in the same format. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    {
        // Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
        // coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
        GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                                longitude:151.20
                                                                     zoom:6];
        mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
        mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
        self.view = mapView_;

        // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
        marker.title = @"Sydney";
        marker.snippet = @"Australia";
        marker.map = mapView_;

        GMSMarker *marker1 = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker1.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-32.92, 151.78);
        marker1.title = @"Newcastle";
        marker1.snippet = @"Australia";
        marker1.map = mapView_;
    }
}
```

Comment: if i want 100 marker so in ur code i need create manually 100 GMSMarker object. this is right way?

Comment: can you please suggest me how to solve more than one marker( example 100 marker) at the same location.i want to click particulay marker.it is difficult. so i want http://www.yourmapper.com/demo/spiderfy.htm animation. any idea?

Comment: @Kittu why do you want so many markers at the same location? eg, Is this an office building?

Comment: @meghan66 in my application user send requests to a server with lat and lngs. IN details user can see the request locations on maps. suppose i send  100 request from same location markers are over lapping. so i am unable to click on particular marker for event action.

Comment: Sorry, it's been awhile since I played with google maps. Didn't mean to lead you on. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    Lat=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"22.5851",@"22.5830002",@"22.5831",@"22.3932",@"22.3409", nil];
         Long=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"88.3468",@"88.33729089999997",@"88.2833",@"87.7427",@"87.3258", nil];
       GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:22.5851
                                                            longitude:88.3468
                                                                 zoom:6];
     GMSMapView *mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    self.view = mapView_;
      for (int i=0; i<[Lat count]; i++) {



    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[Lat objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue], [[Long objectAtIndex:i]doubleValue]);
    marker.title = @"Any Titel";
    marker.snippet = @"India";
    marker.map = mapView_;

}
}
```