# I am trying to display multiple markers and a line between them on google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps-sdk-ios

```
for (int i=0; i<self.busRoutesArr.count-1; i++)
{
    NSString *lat = [self.latArr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *lon = [self.longArr objectAtIndex:i] ;
    double lt=[lat doubleValue];
    double ln=[lon doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f",lt,ln);

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:lt
                                                            longitude:ln
                                                                 zoom:60];


    GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 250, 250) camera:camera];

    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = camera.target;
    marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
    marker.map = mapView;
    mapView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:mapView];
}
```

> Only 1 marker being displayed. I want to display all the markers and a line connecting them

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21531974/how-do-i-create-multiple-markers-for-google-maps-in-my-ios-app

Comment: its working with small changes and a loop. May i know the idle zoom value to see all these markers.

Comment: you need to take out of for loop `GMSMapView *mapView`

Comment: i got everything except drawing line between 9 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is for displaying all markers in the map.

```
for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)    {       
      GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
      marker.animated=YES;
      marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
      marker.title = @"name";
      marker.snippet = @"snippet";
      marker.map = mapView;    
}
```

Comment: i got everything except drawing line between 9 points from array